# Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 5.36

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I try to solve the Ex 5.36 from Boyd & Vandenberghe's Additional Exercises for Convex Optimization and I'm a bit confused. This problem says that:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wif0E.png)

I wrote the Lagrangian:
$g(\lambda, \nu) = \inf\limits_{x \in R^n} L(x, \lambda, \nu) = \inf\limits_{x \in R^n} \left(f_0(x) + \lambda \cdot (f_1(x) - s) + \nu \cdot (Ax - b)\right).$

How are the rest dealt with? I will be glad for any help. Thank you!